# SQL Parameters in For Loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm starting to refactor my code to use 'best' practices in my asp.net application.

One of the big refactors I'm doing is changing the way I use SQL (ado.net) on my application. I've changed all queries where I retrieve information based off of user input to be done through stored procedures taking input parameters to reduce load on the application and keep database items at a database level. I'm also changing an insert statement I allow the user to do onto the database to use Paramaters rather than taken directly from a list of strings.

However, I've noticed myself repeating my code a total of 23 times now. My code is screaming for some sort of loop but I can't think of how to do it. I've looked at foreach loops but it wouldn't work.

I've attached my code below. Could one of you help me by giving me the correct loop for best practice to use and an example of it being used (please do not write the code for me as I'd like to understand it), but show me how the loop works.

Code:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H0", list[0]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H1", list[1]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H2", list[2]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H3", list[3]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H4", list[4]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H5", list[5]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H6", list[6]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H7", list[7]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H8", list[8]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H9", list[9]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H10", list[10]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H11", list[11]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H12", list[12]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H13", list[13]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H14", list[14]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H15", list[15]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H16", list[16]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H17", list[17]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H18", list[18]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H19", list[19]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H20", list[20]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H21", list[21]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H22", list[22]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H23", list[23]);
```

Comment: You might want to look at [table valued paramters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) that allow you to pass a list of data to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a normal `for` loop like this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < list.Length; index++)
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@H" + index.ToString(), list[index]);
}
```

However, I would recommend that you [do *not* use](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) `AddWithValue` as it can have unintended consequences. Instead do something like this:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@H" + index.ToString(), SqlDbType.Int).Value = list[index];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works. And I'll also look at using 'Add' after reading that article. Although, I saw somewhere that .Add is out of date compared to AddWithValue?

Comment: No idea where you read that, if you find the link please share as I'm pretty sure it's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

this should do it, assuming list is a List and not an array

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.Count ; i++)
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@H{0}",i),list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works as intended just like DavidG answer.